# how to add field on admin panel for adding custom html code in wordpress?

Tags: html, wordpress, textarea

how i can add a field in wordpress for adding custom html from backend

like i add

```
    <div class="test">
<h4>Who will solve this Question?</h4>
</div>
```

this html code from that field like Textarea field

& already have declared css for  test class & test h4
like

```
.test .h4{
font-weight:bold;
}
```

so result on front end would be displayed as

**Who will solve this Question?**

Answer (score 0):

You can insert here your HTML:
Admin Panel -> Appearance -> Widgets -> Text.

Or edit your current theme files by hands.

Comment: Installed The Events Calendar PLUGIN i need custom field there that user input html code & get result on event detail page like we do for post,found the solution adding custom fields & there you can easily insert html code, & for text widget we need to install execphp plugin..

Answer (score 0):

Install [this plugin](http://wpgogo.com/development/custom-field-template.html) which will create a automatic custom field.once installed visit your pages and post that will display under Pages/Posts

if you have any querys let me know

Comment: that can be done with coding where there is no support for custom fields there with code add custom-fields to 'supports' => array('custom-fields'), & that will add a custom field in post/Event section & then display those custom field values using get_post_meta($post_id, $key, $single);

Answer (score 0):

@Alex Nevsky you are right.

@Imagine you can add your code by many ways

1)Open from Admin Panel -> Appearance -> Widgets

And from installed widgets area drag and drop "text" plugin into where ever you want(ie,Widget area you want).Then enter your code

`<div class="test">
     <h4>Who will solve this Question?</h4>
  </div>`

in that.
And add style attributes

```
.test .h4
{
     font-weight:bold;
}
```

in style.css file

2)If you want to add specific code in your header or footer.Then this will help you

Install "header and footer" plugin.Under Settings one more option "header or footer" appears  .Click that and add your code.